# Installing a font under Mac OS

Tags: fonts, mactex

I would like to install this font http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html for laTeX on my Mac
but I can't find how. The other threads seems to have success with

```
getnonfreefonts
```

whick I have installed but it does not seem to work with this package for Mac.

Comment: getnonfreefonts and getnonfreefonts-sys can install particular fonts as listed with the -l flag. You can't use it to install arbitrary fonts. Do you know if any support packages are available? Also, do you want to use the font with LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX or what? I actually wrote support to use both Fontin and FontinSans with pdfLaTeX when I was on a Mac although I don't have them installed for TeX right now. However, the fonts can't be distributed so I could give you my source but not a usable package.

Comment: Hi, I want to use it for XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

Any TrueType or OpenType font can be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX just by installing it as a regular system font.

Just download the OpenType or TrueType version of the font(s) and install them as a regular system font (i.e., in `/Library/Fonts`) and they will work with XeTeX or LuaTeX using the `fontspec` package.